# How do I make an if statement that creates output from a user inputed string?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am trying to take a user inputted string and run an if statement that checks if the user inputted string is the desired input.

However, when I run the following program I seem to always get "false" printed even when I input the desired string. I believe it has something to do with the (str == "ABCD") but I am not sure. How can I rewrite this to output "true" when the desired string is input.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

String str = keyboard.nextLine(); //say the user inputs ABCD

if (str == "ABCD")
{
System.out.print(true);
} else {
System.out.print(false);
}
```

Comment: compareString with .equals("stufftocompare")

Comment: You can't compare Strings in Java with == Just use str.equals("ABC");

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare Strings like that in Java.

You can use `str.equals()` if a string should match exactly 
or use `str.equalsIgnoreCase()` for non-casesensitive checks